# FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance crashes with NullPointerException

Tags: firebase, firebase-remote-config

I'm seeing bunch of crashes inside Crashlitics which are coming from most recent **Firebase 15.0.0** on attempt to get FirebaseRemoteConfig

```
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.internal.config.zzar.zzc(long)' on a null object reference
com.google.firebase.remoteconfig.FirebaseRemoteConfig. (Unknown Source)
com.google.firebase.remoteconfig.FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance (Unknown Source)
com.google.firebase.remoteconfig.FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance (Unknown Source)
```

`FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance` is called during `Application.onCreate` and it worked fine on all previous versions.

Build:

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:15.0.0"
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
```

Does anyone see it? Any solutions or workarounds?

P.S. I've sent bug report to firebase team via https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/
https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/474

Comment: Please edit your question to include the contents of your app's build.gradle.

Comment: Updated with build info. There is some progress on the issue I've raised for quickstart sample on github

Comment: Please include your entire build.gradle, not just a fragment.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing - nothing substantial changed from versions of my app (which didn't have that crash), so I believe this is a bug w/ Play Services 15.0.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/474 is't fixed with 15.0.2 update to Firebase RemoteConfig